# Flutter FutureBuilder refreshes all the UI with data reload

Tags: flutter, dart, asynchronous, future

I have a FutureBuilder that gets data from an API, I'll be reloading this data a lot, so the FutureBuilder will refresh a lot.

The problem I'm having is the entire widget structure gets rebuilt every time, and the ListViews and scrolls get reset back to their original positions. I want only the OrderStack to be rebuilt in place. Is this possible? If so how?

```
class ServingStationScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const ServingStationScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  ServingStationScreenState createState() => ServingStationScreenState();
}

class ServingStationScreenState extends State<ServingStationScreen> {

  late Future<Map<String, List<Order>>> ordersFuture;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    ordersFuture = getOrders();
  }

  Future<Map<String, List<Order>>> getOrders() async {
    try {
      var orders = (await APIService().getOrders())!;
      return {
        'ordered': orders.where((order) {
          return order.itemsOrdered!.isNotEmpty;
        }).toList(),
        'preparingAndAwaitingCancellation': orders.where((order) {
          return order.itemsPreparingAndAwaitingCancellation!.isNotEmpty;
        }).toList(),
      };
    } catch (e) {
      return Future.error(e);
    }
  }

  final List<String> emptyImages = [
    'assets/svg/barbecue.svg',
    'assets/svg/beer.svg',
    'assets/svg/breakfast.svg',
    'assets/svg/cooking.svg',
    'assets/svg/fresh-drink.svg',
    'assets/svg/ice-cream.svg',
    'assets/svg/mint-tea.svg',
    'assets/svg/pizza.svg',
    'assets/svg/special-event.svg',
    'assets/svg/tea.svg',
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: Navigation(
        allowBack: false,
        activePage: 'Serving Station',
        restaurantName: 'Test Restaurant',
        actions: [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 10),
            child: IconButton(
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  ordersFuture = getOrders();
                });
                // Get.to(() => const ServingStationHistoryScreen());
              },
              icon: const Icon(
                Icons.history_rounded,
                color: Colors.white,
                size: 26.0,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
      backgroundColor: const Color.fromRGBO(21, 21, 32, 1),
      body: FutureBuilder(
        future: ordersFuture,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          switch(snapshot.connectionState) {
            case ConnectionState.none:
            case ConnectionState.waiting:
            case ConnectionState.active:
              return const CircularProgressIndicator(
                color: Color.fromRGBO(93, 194, 188, 1),
              );
            case ConnectionState.done:
              if(snapshot.hasError) {
                return Center(
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 100),
                        child: Opacity(
                          opacity: 0.5,
                          child: SvgPicture.asset(
                            'assets/svg/server.svg',
                            height: SizerUtil.deviceType == DeviceType.tablet ? 500 : 200,
                            theme: const SvgTheme(
                              currentColor: Color.fromRGBO(93, 194, 188, 1),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Text(
                        'Service Unreachable',
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: SizerUtil.deviceType == DeviceType.tablet ? 30 : 18, color: Colors.white),
                      ),
                      Text(
                        'Error: ${snapshot.error}',
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: SizerUtil.deviceType == DeviceType.tablet ? 15 : 10, color: Colors.red),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                );
              } else {
                final data = snapshot.data as Map<String, List<Order>>;
                return data['preparingAndAwaitingCancellation']!.isNotEmpty || data['ordered']!.isNotEmpty ? SafeArea(
                  bottom: false,
                  child: ListView(
                    shrinkWrap: false,
                    children: [
                      data['preparingAndAwaitingCancellation']!.isNotEmpty ? Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          Container(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20, left: 20, bottom: 20),
                            child: Row(
                              children: [
                                const Text('Current Items',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                    fontSize: 30,
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Container(
                                  margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, right: 10),
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 5, right: 5, top: 2, bottom: 2),
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                      color: Colors.yellow[200],
                                      border: Border.all(
                                        color: Colors.transparent,
                                      ),
                                      borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20))
                                  ),
                                  child: const Text(
                                    'Preparing',
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.black,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                      fontSize: 15,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Container(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 5, right: 5, top: 2, bottom: 2),
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                      color: Colors.red[200],
                                      border: Border.all(
                                        color: Colors.transparent,
                                      ),
                                      borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20))
                                  ),
                                  child: const Text(
                                    'Awaiting Cancellation',
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.black,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                      fontSize: 15,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                          SingleChildScrollView(
                            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                            child: SizedBox(
                              width: data['preparingAndAwaitingCancellation']!.length * 500 < 2500 ? data['preparingAndAwaitingCancellation']!.length * 500 : 2500,
                              child: MasonryGridView.count(
                                physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                                crossAxisCount: data['preparingAndAwaitingCancellation']!.length < 5 ? data['preparingAndAwaitingCancellation']!.length : 5,
                                mainAxisSpacing: 10,
                                crossAxisSpacing: 10,
                                shrinkWrap: true,
                                itemCount: data['preparingAndAwaitingCancellation']!.length,
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20),
                                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                  return OrderStack(
                                    order: data['preparingAndAwaitingCancellation']![index],
                                    filter: OrderStatusFilter.preparingAndAwaitingCancellation,
                                  );
                                },
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ) : Container(),
                      data['ordered']!.isNotEmpty ? Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          Container(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20, left: 20, bottom: 20),
                            child: Row(
                              children: [
                                const Text('New Items',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                    fontSize: 30,
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Container(
                                  margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, right: 10),
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 5, right: 5, top: 2, bottom: 2),
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                      border: Border.all(
                                        color: Colors.transparent,
                                      ),
                                      borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20))
                                  ),
                                  child: const Text(
                                    'Ordered',
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.black,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                      fontSize: 15,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                          SingleChildScrollView(
                            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                            child: SizedBox(
                              width: data['ordered']!.length * 500 < 2500 ? data['ordered']!.length * 500 : 2500,
                              child: MasonryGridView.count(
                                physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                                crossAxisCount: data['ordered']!.length < 5 ? data['ordered']!.length : 5,
                                mainAxisSpacing: 10,
                                crossAxisSpacing: 10,
                                shrinkWrap: true,
                                itemCount: data['ordered']!.length,
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20),
                                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                  return OrderStack(
                                    order: data['ordered']![index],
                                    filter: OrderStatusFilter.ordered,
                                  );
                                },
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ) : Container(),
                    ],
                  ),
                ) : Center(
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 100),
                        child: Opacity(
                          opacity: 0.5,
                          child: SvgPicture.asset(
                            emptyImages.elementAt(Random().nextInt(emptyImages.length)),
                            height: SizerUtil.deviceType == DeviceType.tablet ? 500 : 200,
                            theme: const SvgTheme(
                              currentColor: Color.fromRGBO(93, 194, 188, 1),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Text(
                        'There are currently no pending orders.',
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: SizerUtil.deviceType == DeviceType.tablet ? 30 : 18, color: Colors.white),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                );
              }
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: `ValueLidtenableBuilder` for example?

Comment: Does ValueListenableBuilder work for complex objects inside future builder? @pskink

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should drop your `FutureBuilder` as far down your widget tree as possible, wrapping only the widgets that are affected by that future. It looks like you have a `SingleChildScrollView` that holds the `OrderStack`, so you might wrap only that widget in the `FutureBuilder`. Then, only that portion of the UI is updated when the `ordersFuture` completes.

Also, if this is essentially a stream of data, then consider using `StreamBuilder` instead - `FutureBuilder` is typically used to wait for one-time completion of a task, once (e.g. loading the data to display in a list), not necessarily to refresh it.

Comment: I followed your advice and switched to a StreamBuilder, however, my StreamBuilder doesn't get executed, can you please check my code here?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73759281/streambuilder-not-reacting-to-items-getting-added-to-streamcontroller-sink